# Ping using PHP Exec to return information

Tags: php, html, exec, ping

I am trying to get a database that analyzes pings and stores information.

Right now, I am having problems with receiving the ping at all. I have looked at previous questions that have been asked and I have pretty much the same answers except I do not have php.ini enabled. I am not sure where exactly to put that.

This is the code I have so far:

```
if ($_POST['Ping']){
    //store the address the user gave as a variable called address
$address = $_POST["address"];
exec("ping -n 3 $address",$output,$status);
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($output as $line) echo htmlspecialchars("$line\n"); 
 echo "</pre>";


}
```

I have also tried:

```
$pingresult = exec("ping  -n 3 $address", $outcome, $status);
 echo $pingresult
```

This gives me a problem saying that conversion to string from array.

Comment: If you're trying to debug the results of exec than use `var_dump($pingresult);` instead of echo.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the value of `$status` on return. Doing so, you'd probably find it to be non-zero. Entering `ping -n 3 192.168.0.1` on the commandline will probably give you an error message: `connect: Invalid argument`

Here's what you should do:

1. Alter your code to check that `$address` contains a valid address before calling ping
2. Alter your code to check the return values for exec for errors.
3. Check that the parameters entered for ping are the correct ones. `ping -n 3 address` won't work on my system, producing an error message and a non-zero exit status, but `ping -c 3 address` will give me three attempts to ping `address`.